# Need help in evaluating $\int \sin^2x\cos x\sqrt{9-2\sin^2x}dx$

Tags: calculus

the textbook suggests a substitution... wanted to see if one of you could figure out the right one... thanks!

$$\int \sin^2x\cos x\sqrt{9-2\sin^2x}dx$$

I'm sure it lies under the substitution... but I'm not quite sure. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Why don't you try a substitution, and see whether it works? You can't break anything --- the worst thing that could happen is it doesn't work, and then you try something different. You will learn more by trying stuff than by reading answers from someone else.

Comment: For most integrals involving trig expressions, substitution of $y = \sin(x)$ or $y = \cos(x)$ will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a better substitution would be

$$\sin{t} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \sin{x}$$

$$\cos{t} dt = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \cos{x} dx$$

The integral then becomes

$$\frac{81}{4} \int dt \: \cos^2{t} \sin^2{t}$$

which I think the reader can take from here.